# Change/update the default user profile photo/thumbnail folder location

Tags: image, default

I'm having a hell of a time tracking where i can change/update the default user profile photo/thumbnail folder location. I keep reading and have tested that you can create a new volume for assets. My interest is is being able to locate and change the default folder location. Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

In Craft 3 the place that users photos get stored in are proper Asset Volumes, meaning they can be stored in a folder on the local file system, or on S3, Google Cloud, or any other place that a plugin provides a Volume for.

Once you create a Volume for user photos, go to Settings->Users->Settings in the Control Panel and you can choose that Volume under the "User Photo Volume" settings.

Comment: Thanks Brad! Yeah, I got it squared away last night. Such a simple adjustment that I kept overlooking due to other tasks I wanted to complete for my initial base build of Craft 3. Thank you so much for responding! Eddie

Answer (score 1):

I am only able to speak about Craft 2x, as I am not familiar at all with how Craft 3 handles profile images.

Here is where Craft 2x stores any uploaded profile image:

```
/craft/storage/userphotos/
```

It is kind of a special asset source that isn't accessible like you would find an asset field that you create is. You *can* render the image, but as far as I know, you are not able to change it's location.

Hope this helps!